# Pyomo constraint function: Which is more expensive, embedding if-else within the function or create a new binary parameter in the expression?

Tags: if-statement, optimization, binary, constraints, pyomo

While creating a constraint definition for pyomo model with time-series (8760-step) indices, some parts of expression needs to be left out, conditional to a user-defined input (True/False)

(a) def balance(model, t): if grid: return ...  else: return ...

(b) model.gridBinary = pyo.Param(within=pyo.Binary, initialize=user_input)

def balance(model, t): return model.gridBinary * (grid-related variables) + ...

In (a), will the programme do an if-else check in every 8760 step, and lead to a more expensive run than (b)? Which version reflects a better programming practice?

Attempted both but turns out (b) runs faster than (a)